# Windows native spellcheck is too slow if used word per word. Can I do anything to speed it up?

Tags: c++, windows, com, spell-checking

I've tried to support usage windows native spell-checking support in my library. Some examples of its usage could be found here:

https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/08/01/using-the-c-spell-checking-api.aspx

And since I perform word tokenization myself I ended up calling its `Check` function for every single word and checking if there is an error or not. However as it turns out this workflow is incredibly slow with Windows spellchecker, checking ~750 words takes more than a second and results in clear and visible lag. While other commonly used spell-checking libraries (Hunspell, Aspell) work much faster in this case.

Profiler shows me a lot of COM related machinery and functions like `FindStdMarshal` doing most of indiviudual work. I don't know much about COM and is it justified or not. My code mostly seems to wait in `Check` function. I could transfter this function out of main thread but that would not of course resolve the problem entirely.

Is it inner deficiency in Windows spell-checker and I have to get out of my way to combine words together and then check them or am I doing something wrong and there is a better workflow available?

Edit:
Here's an example:
https://gist.github.com/Predelnik/af58986b25eeec03b546a826b17b821c
First checking loop takes approx. 1 second on my machine (number of words ~750)
Second check of combined string takes 0.001 (less than precision) on my machine essentially returning the same information.

It may be a bit harder to create repropducible example with hunspell/aspell but I believe it takes close to 0 seconds for both cases.

Comment: I guess you should provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the stated performance problem.

Comment: Give Hunspell a chance... ;)

Comment: Also show us some code you have. Maybe there are some unneeded roundtripps.

Comment: I tried to write standalone example and performance actually looks much better in it. I will try to play around for a bit to see what's actually different.

Comment: So I've created my example but figured that I failed at measuring my scale a little bit, it takes 1 second to spell check ~750 words (not 30 as I written) one by one which may make you question why I spellcheck so many at once but that's beside the point :) Hunspell still lightning fast with this, is it just downside of using managed COM objects in this case?